# Get Sonarqube Analysis Status on a variable (GUI Job)

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I couldn't find any solutions to this particular need.

Basically I have a **GUI Job** and I need the status of the Sonarqube Analysis so I can later send a POST Request with it.

*(I'm aware that pipeline exists and works great but because a specific reason I need it to be GUI)*

On the pipeline you have the `WaitForQualityGate.status()`, I've tried using this but no success.

[Example of what is desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuME1.png)

Any insights? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SonarQube Rest API to get the status.

Whenever you run SonarQube analysis through Jenkins Pipeline, upon the successful analysis you will see **report-task.txt** created in the workspace folder.

> **Note:** The location of **report-task.txt** file depends on the tool that was used to generate it. The `mvn sonar:sonar` task defaults to path `target/sonar`. In my case, I used sonarscanner to analyse a nodejs project. So the location of **report-tast.txt** is `.scannerwork`.

[image]

Now, you will get the **ceTaskUrl** and **ceTaskId** in `report-task.txt`. You can use that **ceTaskUrl** to get the **analysisId**.

Then, you can use the below api to get the quality gate status using **analysisId**.

`http://<sonarqube_host>/api/qualitygates/project_status?analysisId=$ANALYSIS_ID"`

Now, try to get the curl output of the above API into a variable.

Comment: That worked! I was skeptical on using the API for this but works like a charm. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to say that you want a custom variable message to pop up in your Jenkins GUI based on the SonarQube scan status, then that would require you to:

1. Clone the original Jenkins source code
2. Add a custom HTML button/div/graphic
3. Compile the Jenkins code
4. Build the new code
5. Execute the generated JAR

Else, you can try some plugins available on Jenkins that would give you the ability to render conditional outputs. No promises on whether they can actually help you change the original GUI.

Any alternative traditional approach wouldn't be able to fulfill your GUI requirement.